# Why can't a struct inherit from a class, but all structs inherit from the class "object"?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
public class C {}
public struct S : C {}
public class Test
{
    public static void Main() {}
}
```

This doesn't compile. Every struct implicitly inherits from the class `ValueType`, which inherits from the class `object`. How is this possible?

Comment: It is possible because the language designers designed and implemented it this way. I don't see how this is interesting?

Comment: I mean, how is it realized on the lower levels?

Comment: Does this remarks section offer any help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-7.0#remarks (3rd paragraph)

Comment: The runtime doesn't have to obey the same rules that your code has to.

Answer (score 0):

A Structure is a type of value, not a class. Structures cannot inherit from another class or structure. You should consider reading the documentation about structures [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct).